# wpf datagrid custom header reserves space when data is collapsed

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagridview

I have a column with a custom header in my `DataGrid`. Part of the header needs to disappear when a user enables a `CheckBox` (named: show). I can see the text disappearing when I enable the `CheckBox`, but the width doesn't get adjusted, so they still reserve the space they used to.

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn.Header>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="Name" Margin="0,0,35,0" />
        <TextBlock Text="Date" Margin="0,0,35,0" Visibility="{Binding Path=IsChecked,Source={x:Reference show}, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVis}}" />
        <TextBlock Text="Address" Margin="0,0,35,0" Visibility="{Binding Path=IsChecked,Source={x:Reference show}, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVis}}" />
        <TextBlock Text="Tel" Margin="0,0,35,0" Visibility="{Binding Path=IsChecked,Source={x:Reference show}, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVis}}" />
        <TextBlock Text="Mobile" Margin="0,0,35,0" />
    </StackPanel>
</telerik:GridViewDataColumn.Header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the width yourself. The `DataGrid` won't dynamically change the width of the column for you.

The easiest way to do this would probably be to handle the `SizeChanged` event of the `StackPanel` in the code-behind of the view (this is purely view- or control-based logic):

```
private void StackPanel_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    colX.Width = ((StackPanel)sender).ActualWidth;
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn x:Name="colX" DataMemberBinding="{Binding X}">
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.Header>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" SizeChanged="StackPanel_SizeChanged">
            <TextBlock Text="Name" Margin="0,0,35,0" />
            <TextBlock Text="Date" Margin="0,0,35,0" Visibility="{Binding Path=IsChecked,Source={x:Reference show}, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVis}}" />
            <TextBlock Text="Address" Margin="0,0,35,0" Visibility="{Binding Path=IsChecked,Source={x:Reference show}, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVis}}" />
            <TextBlock Text="Tel" Margin="0,0,35,0" Visibility="{Binding Path=IsChecked,Source={x:Reference show}, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVis}}" />
            <TextBlock Text="Mobile" Margin="0,0,35,0" />
        </StackPanel>
    </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.Header>
</telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
```